# Docker - Selenium Grid -> container with windows and FF or with mac os and safari

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-grid

I need a help with docker. I am rooki when it comes to use it but I need it for selenium GRID. I found only conteiners for selenium with different browser like IE, chrome or FF but all of them on linux. The problem is that I dont wanna test linux but I want to test using FF but on Windows OS or using Safari and MAC OS.
Can anyone tell me how to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: where did you find IE inside Linux? I would like to see that one.

Comment: Maybe i didn't. It doesnt matter in this case

Comment: I think is better not to put false or misleading information, will confuse people.